# Kepler scientific workflow system integration in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, workflow

I'm trying to integrate the Kepler workflow system in Eclipse, but I have problems:

[image: error screenshot]

When I try to run any project or install any additional plugin, I get the error

> An internal error occurred during: "Compute launch button tooltip" org/python/pydev/navigator/elements/IWrappedResource

What is the reason for that, and how can I fix it?